Are there other usual ways of justifying the passage of differentiation into integral?
I am recently reading Evan's Partial Differential Equations.
In the book, the author sometimes passage differentiation into integrals (i.e. $\frac{\text{d}(\int_{\Omega} f(\mathbf{x},y)\text{d}\mathbf{x})}{\text{d}y}=\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x},y)}{\partial y}\text{d}\mathbf{x}$) without justifying it (like this post),
and I usually struggle proving this passage is reasonable in such case.
So my question is: Since Evans did not list any particular analysis book as prerequisite, nor talked about changing differentiation and integral in the appendix,
are there any usual ways of justifying the passage of differentiation into integral that Evans assumes the readers know, but I am missing?
There are three ways I know that can guarantee the passage of differentiation into integral is correct:

Apply Dominated Convergence Theorem to
$$\left( f_h(y)= \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{e}_i,y)-f(\mathbf{x},y)}{h}\right)_{h\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)}.    $$
where $f_h\to \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ pointwise.

If $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on $[a,+\infty)\times[b,c]$,
$\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\text{d} x   $ exists for each $y\in [b,c]$,
and $\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \text{d} x $ converges uniformly wrt $y\in [b,c]$ (meaning $$\sup_{y\in [b,c]}\left( \int_{A}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \text{d} x\right)\to 0,\, A\to +\infty    $$), then $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \text{d} x=\frac{\text{d} (\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x,y) \text{d} x)}{\text{d}y}  .\, (y\in [b,c])$$

If $f:[a,b]\times [c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ and the integral $\int_a^b f(x,y)\text{d} x$ is proper for each $y\in [c,d]$, and $f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$,
then $$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \text{d} x=\frac{\text{d} (\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y) \text{d} x)}{\text{d}y} .\, (y\in [c,d]) $$


(I have only learned the $x\in \mathbb{R}$ version of 2,3 in my analysis course. But I think they can be generalized to higher dimension $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$).
Is there any other usual way of changing integral and differentiation sign I am missing?

Part 1 with the mean value theorem or fundamental theorem of calculus to make the bound simple is usually sufficient.

Thanks for your comment! I did not realize Part 1 can be combined with the mean value theorem before. Part 1 plus the mean value theorem is indeed a powerful tool handling such problem.
